# Is there a way to specify a .pem key within bitbucket-pipelines.xml?

Tags: authentication, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, remote-server, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a build from bitbucket via bitbucket pipelines.
Basically what I need is to copy the static build files into a remote server.
This server requires a .pem file for authentication.
I have tried specifying this key in the following ways:

1. As a repository variable
2. As a file within the repository itself and pointing to it within the build XML.
3. As a parameter for scp-deploy.

But in all cases the same issue occurs:

> Host key verification failed. lost connection error Command failed
> with exit code 1.

So, would be a great help if someone could tell me how to specify this within the bitbucket-pipelines.xml file for a smooth build.

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines run within a docker container. There could be 2 ways 2 do it -

- You can add the .pem file content in secret repo var, write the content in a file and name it like something.pem, replace the configuration xml file with the generated file location;
  Secret repo var looks like: Name - MY_PEM Value - Some encrypted content
  In you pipeline:
  To write the file locally:
  echo $MY_PEM > my.pem
  To replace the fiel path in config XML
  sed -i "s/{A Placeholder In Your XML}/${MY_PEM_PATH}/g" path/to/your/config.xml
- Bundle the .pem file within a docker container and deploy the container in a private container registry(E.g. - Google Cloud, AWS etc.). Use that container as your base image.